# perl regex help matching any characters except trailing space

Tags: regex, perl

looking for some perl help. I'm not good with regexes. But here's basically what I need help with:

```
-strip out the leading blank line
-regex for any value after the directory `/foo/bar/set`, excluding trailing spaces
```

Expected output:

```
55
proxy
test.event.done
```

Test Input file:

```
<leading blank :line here>     
/foo/bar/set/55
/foo/bar/set/proxy
/foo/bar/set/test.event.done
```

Code:

```
while(my $line=<>) {
    chomp($line);
    if ($line =~ m#foo/bar/set/(not sure what to match here) {
        print "$line\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the problem that you don’t know how to write `\S+`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(.*) matches everything in the line and you can get the value from $1.
use this to test your regex: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: No, never use something else to test a regex! Use Perl.

Comment: maybe for you..but there are people new to this topic

Answer (score 2):

```
while (<>) {        
    if (m|^/foo/bar/set/(\S+)|) {
        print "$1\n";
    }       
}
```

Comment: @euguene - thanks for your reply. can you tell me what the `next if` is doing?

Comment: What the heck is `[^\s]`? Isn’t that `\S`?

Comment: @tchrist: sure. time to go to sleep

Answer (score 2):

If the input is a directory path and if you need to extract the filename, you can 
use the basename methods of the Perl File::Basename module.

```
use File::Basename;
$filename = basename ($dirpath);
```